# how to add multiple rows from select request in another select request

Tags: sql

I have two select requests. One which can return only one row and another which can return until 5 rows, for each request there is a join between them.

What I want to do is to add the rows from the second select (the one with can have until 5 rows) to the first select. With this I will have only one rows with all information.

For example if my first select has 5 columns and the second select return 2 rows with 4 columns I will have only one rows with 13 columns (5 + 2 x 4). Or if the second select return 3 rows i will have 17 columns (5 + 3 x 4).

I've spent quite a lot of time looking at that but I didn't found any result for my case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, It could be helpful for you https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp, I think that you require to get understand more about SQL.

Comment: It would probably be helpful for you to first go through an SQL tutorial so you can then provide some concrete code if you can't manage to find a solution.

It's easier to get an answer in StackOverflow if you show what have you tried before, as opposed to just asking for a direct solution.

Comment: But if I add a join, it will return the number of rows from the second select with always the same colums value from the first slect + the colums from the second select. it's not that i want

Comment: First, learn some SQL.  Second, learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When you join two select results (First result gives one row, second result gives 5 rows) and if the first result set row column matches with second result set row columns, then you will have 5 rows coming.

Movie Table

```
----------+---------+
+ MovieId +MovieName+
----------+---------+
    1       Ben Hur
----------+---------+
```

Movie Order Details Table

```
-----------+----------+------------+------------+
MovieId    + Orderedby+ OrederedOn + ReturnedOn +
-----------+----------+------------+ -----------+
1          + Venkat   +  2015/06/01   2015/06/02 +
1          + Raman    +  2014/07/01   2014/07/02 +
1          + David    +  2017/07/01   2017/07/02 +
1          + George   +  2018/07/01   2018/07/02 +
-----------+----------+------------+--------------
```

When you join Movie table(select 1) & Movie Order Details Table(select 2), you will get 4 rows , as they are matching with first select MovieId.

```
SELECT M.MovieId, M.MovieName, d.Orderby, d.OrderedOn, d.ReturnedOn 
FROM Movie AS M
JOIN MovieOrderDetails AS d
ON M.MovieId = d.MovieId

--------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+
MovieId + MovieName   + Orderedby+ OrederedOn + ReturnedOn +
--------+-------------+----------+------------+ -----------+
1       + Ben Hur     + Venkat   +  2015/06/01   2015/06/02 +
1       + Ben Hur     + Raman    +  2014/07/01   2014/07/02 +
1       + Ben Hur     + David    +  2017/07/01   2017/07/02 +
1       + Ben Hur     + George   +  2018/07/01   2018/07/02 +
--------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------
```